# ImportError: cannot import name 'Tk'

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am writing a program in python on ubuntu, but since couple of days I am facing this problem which is very irratating,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tansen/Documents/python2/button25_01JanV1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Tkinter,ttk
  File "/home/tansen/Documents/python2/Tkinter.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
ImportError: cannot import name 'Tk'
```

before that this program was running OK, and I run several time program successfully

```
import tkinter.ttk 
from tkinter import *


def viewFile():

    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()


    step = LabelFrame(root,text="FILE MANAGER", font = "Arial 20 bold   italic")
    step.grid(row=1, columnspan=7, sticky='W',padx=100, pady=5, ipadx=130, ipady=25)

    Button(step,    text="OpenFile",    font = "Arial 8 bold    italic",    activebackground="turquoise",   width=30, height=5, command=viewFile).grid      (row= 6, column =3)
    Button(step,    text="Exit",        font = "Arial 8 bold    italic",    activebackground="turquoise",   width=20, height=5, command=root.quit).grid     (row= 6, column =5)

    tex = Text(master=root)                                                                 # TextBox For Displaying File Information
    scr=Scrollbar(root,orient =VERTICAL,command=tex.yview)
    scr.grid(row=8, column=2, rowspan=15, columnspan=1, sticky=NS)
    tex.grid(row=8, column=1, sticky=E)
    tex.config(yscrollcommand=scr.set,font=('Arial', 8, 'bold', 'italic'))

    root.mainloop()
```

As advice by the experts I rename the file Tkinter.py and change the caps from 'T' to 't'. After that my program is running successfully but another issue has created. Pressing of exit button is not working.

[image]

Can you please help to get rid from this problem successfully.

Comment: In Py3, it is `tkinter` ( with a small `t` )

Comment: after that I am getting this error
ImportError: No module named 'ttk'

Comment: I have no idea what is the different b/w py2 and py3? I am thinking that it is just a upgrade version

Comment: Instead of import *, can you import only the classes you need, and also delete all your pyc files?  Use pyclean . in your current dir (install pyclean should be easy).  I've had this problem where I named a function or class something that was actually a package import, and one of my old pyc files kept overwriting that variable name when I imported it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You called a file `Tkinter.py` in the same directory, rename it and delete the .pyc

```
/home/tansen/Documents/python2/Tkinter.py <- importing from this not the module
```

You are also using the import syntax for python 2's Tkinter, use:

```
from tkinter import ttk, Text, Button, LabelFrame, VERTICAL, E, NS, Scrollbar, Tk
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham 
After removing Tkinter.py from the folder, it is showing this

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tansen/Documents/python2/button25_01JanV1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter,ttk
ImportError: No module named 'ttk'

Comment: Now I m using python3, before that I think it was Python 2.7.....
do i know plz, what is the difference b/w them

Comment: @PadraicCunningham 

now, it is running the program but my Exit button is not working properly

Comment: @PadraicCunningham

Before that it close the whole window but now it is acting just like a dummy button... root.quit is not working

Comment: @PadraicCunningham
Should I remove pycache folder from the directory?

Comment: You should have renamed Tkinter.py and removed Tkinter.pyc as I suggested but that has nothing to do with what is happening now. Go and run your code with the imports in my answer in ipython or some ide. Your code works fine for me so the code is not the issue.

Comment: Also don't edit your question and change the content, if you have a new problem ask a new question

Comment: @PadraicCunningham
Another compiler Geany is ok after renaming of Tkinter.py...but Geany is running on Python2, not accepting python3 command
Only Idle is running python3 command but root.quit is not working on it

Comment: geany is just an editor, how are you running the fike?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69557/discussion-between-fahad-uddin-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file you are importing is in the same folder as your program. Then, delete the *pycache* folder (or whatever it is called on Ubuntu, I'm using Windows. It will be a "Compiled Python File"). This could have corrupted annd stopped your program from working properly. If this doesn't work, then I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.